# Double Fourier Series $\cos(nx)\cos(my)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, integration, fourier-series

Let $f(x,y) = xy$ on the square $[0, \pi]^2$. Find the Fourier cosine-cosine series of $f$.

I am working on this question with a group and one of us gets all the coefficients as zero. Is this correct or not?

Also, we are at a disagreement about whether to integrate over $[-\pi,\pi]$ or $[-\pi /2,\pi /2]$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot a part of it

Comment: Your title doesn't match your definition of $f$.

Comment: Could you briefly recall how the Fourier cosine-cosine series is defined?

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking because it is a long summation that consist of sines and cosines and sine-cosine and cosine-sine and cosine-cosine and sine-sine.